# Is there a pattern to the order of bosses in the Thunder Dragon's Boss Rush?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I just took about six or seven tries to get the Hylian Shield in Hero Mode. I didn't prepare with Guardian Potion or anything; I wasn't that desperate yet.

I started with Demise (just for fun) three times. Twice, the second boss was the final Imprisoned battle.

I then started with Tentalus three or four times. On all but one of the tries, the second boss was the first Ghirahim battle.

I find these coincidences a bit too unlikely to be due to random chance. Is there a pattern to the order of boss battles depending on which one you pick first? Perhaps for each boss, there are more and less likely bosses that follow that one? Is it perhaps possible to choose a boss that will more likely yield an easy sequence if you're only going for four or eight victories?

Comment: After this, I played several more times, including a complete 12-battle run where I lost (idiotically) on the final battle and another where I won the 9900 Rupees. I didn't document the order, but I feel like there was definitely a pattern. I felt like the game purposely distributes the Ghirahim battles, Imprisoned battles, and regular bosses so that you rarely have the same category back-to-back. And it definitely without a doubt always saves Demise until the last battle, unless you pick it first.

Comment: [Zelda Wiki](http://www.zeldawiki.org/index.php?title=Thunder_Dragon's_Lightning_Round#Boss_Battles) says it's based on how well you perform (no citation). The Prima guide says it's completely random.

Answer (score 2):

With many random number generators, the outcome can be manipulated because they run on an event counter rather thaan the system's internal clock (which is seperate from the one that tells the time).

It seems to me that this is one of those cases, thus resulting in the pseudo random numbers (meaning that they are not so random).

An infamous case of this type of thing is the GameBoy Advance game Golden Sun. You could manipulate the random number generator to make very rare drops a certainty in this game.  It doesn't surprise me that Skyward Sword would do something like that, it is less resource intensive than true random numbers.

Basically, there isnt technically a pattern, but there might as well be.

What leads me to believe this is that one boss almost always got a specific boss in a specific order. In the Golden Sun example, in order to get the rare drop, you had to make the characters perform specific attacks on specific targets in a specific order to get the timing right. For example, character 1 attacks with fire, 2 attacks with ice and three attacks with lightning, but it has to be 3 that attacks first.

It almost ends up looking like its an if statement, which seems to be the case here, if first is tentalus, second has a 90% chance to be ghirahim. I dont think its exactly like that, but they are very similar.

Comment: This seems more like a guess than an answer, can you provide a bit more info or a source that leads you to believe the game works this way?